# If I want to play the same sound 10 times per second, must I have 10 copies of that sound in memory?

Tags: iphone, audio, finch

I have a sound that needs to get played 10 times per second. The sound is 1 second long. So it does overlap like 10 times. However, as far as I understand the Finch sound library, I would need 10 different instances of a sound in place so that I can play it 10 times at almost the same time.

When I have just one instance, the sound would stop and play from the beginning on every iteration, but not overlap with itself.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Finch it depends on how many instances of the particular sound you want to play simultaneously. Pass this number to the `initWithFile:rounds:` initializer of the `RevolverSound` class and it will allocate the desired number of copies of the sample.

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely. Depends on the sound system/card and the API you're using. Usually it's fire and forget (where fire is load the data stream, tell audio system to play stream X times). To get it to overlap, you'd may need to use multiple channels. I'm not familiar with finch to know how it handles that sort of thing.